# Как исправить символы

Tags: javascript, html5

Пишу аудиоплеер.

Задаю ему `src`, потом пытаюсь достать его javascript'ом, и вместо исходного

> "files/fedot/Asking Alexandria- I Won't Give In.mp3"

получаю

> "files/fedot/Asking%20Alexandria-%20I%20Won't%20Give%20In.mp3".

Как вернуть это к нормальному виду?

Comment: [decodeURI()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI)

Comment: @MedvedevDev, оформите как ответ, многие не читают комментарии при поиске ответов

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
console.log(decodeURI("files/fedot/Asking%20Alexandria-%20I%20Won't%20Give%20In.mp3"))
```